# Limit access of GCE, Azure and AWS instances to specific websites

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, cloud, google-compute-engine, firewall

Is there some way to limit access of VM instances from GCE, Azure or AWS to specific websites.
Firewalling is easy but some websites resolve to different IP addresses often. Filtering within the OS is not feasible in this case.
I can only think of some instance sitting between the OS and the internet doing filtering. 
But maybe there is some feature for one of these cloud services which does that?

Comment: Please, try to post what you already tried to do to solve this. Explain this with more details about configuration, code snippet(if necessary), examples, links, etc. using the available tools( You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ) to help you how to edit your question.

Comment: Limit your question to asking about one cloud vendor and specify the service (Compute Engine, App Engine, etc). Your question is too broad and lacks focus.